# How do drain current auto release pool?

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

Normally, we call `@autoreleasepool` to drain the auto release pool in ARC.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    MyObject* object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
}
//do something
```

Now I want all `MyObject` objects drained while I call `MyFunction`.

```
- (void)MyFunction
{
    //[[NSAutoReleasePool defaultAutoReleasePool] drain];
    //do something
}
```

I do know that `@autoreleasepool` create a new pool. I just want `MyFunction` drain default pool or current pool, which can make sure that all unused `MyObject` in autorelease pool is drained in common case.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

`@autoreleasepool { ... }` creates and deletes (drains) a new autoreleasepool. You cannot drain the current autoreleasepool manually. Sometimes it could be necessary to free objects in the pool. In this case you should use nested pools, e.g.:

```
@autoreleasepool { // Initial pool
    ...
    for(...) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            // Using large amount in ARP
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

BTW: The object in your first listing isn't a member of an ARP, because it's a result of an `alloc`-`init` call, and thus you have the ownership to it (see [Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)).